# How i can post credentials from rest client to spring security rest api?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

Good day, everyone!

I have 2 apps.
The first one is spring boot REST API (i run it on "localhost:8080").
The second one is spring boot REST client (it was written via RestTemplate, i run it on "localhost:8090").

I send requests from REST client to REST API and it works good - i get my HTML page with users list.

But i want to have Spring security in my project.

How can i post username and password from REST client to REST API Spring security?

I guess, it may be basic auth or httpClient.

Am i right? Answer me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this problem using the token. The steps look like this:

1. The client will use a login function for the first time, it will send the credentials to the server for asking authenticating.
2. Server will check the credentials to see if it is correct, if yes, it will create a token and return it to client with some other information: groups, role, name,...
3. Whenever the client call an api, it will attach the token in the request header, server needs to have a filter to check the header if it carries a valid token, then authorize that request to access the system.
4. Any api endpoint will check if the client has authorities before executing. The authorities can be provided from the 3rd step.